# How to delete dictionary key-value pairs if a substring is found at the end of more than one key?

Tags: python, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
dictionary = {
'thegreenmile': '1999',
'scarface': '1983',
'fightclub': '1999',
'thebluemile': '1776',
'theyellowmile': '1893'
}
```

I want Python to look through the dictionary. If there are keys that end in identical ways, remove the key-value pairs. In the dictionary above, that means while the key-value pair associated with the key *thegreenmile* remains, the other two key-value pairs associated with the keys *thebluemile* and *theyellowmile* are deleted.

You might ask, "What about the beginning? I see the word *the* duplicated." I'm only focusing on the end, and I haven't been successful in finding something that would allow me to target only the end (I do know about `.strip()`, but that's very different.)

How can I make it so that Python keeps only one key-value pair if it happens that multiple keys share the same ending? I'm thinking of a threshold of four identical characters at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try it this way, if you want to keep multiple values with the same suffix, try saving them in the same list, or in a format like json

```
dictionary = {'thegreenmile': '1999', 'scarface': '1983', 'fightclub': '1999', 'thebluemile': '1776', 'theyellowmile': '1893'}

keys, new_dic = set(), {}
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    if k[-4:] not in keys:
        keys.add(k[-4:])
        new_dic[k] = v
print(new_dic)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! May I ask how you formulated this? I wanna get the logic of this so I can use it in novel situations. I can understand it now that you put it, but actually writing it is difficult, are there any practice problems?